# Discord.py AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'cooldown'

Tags: discord.py

I did a simple command with cooldown but I get an error...

my code:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def...
```

the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'cooldown'
```

A long time ago I used that and that was working so I don't understand, I checked the discord.py API Reference and this is supposed to be correct.

Comment: Try: `@commands.cooldown(1, 60, BucketType.user)`

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Have you imported `from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType`?

Comment: Yes i did but I think the issue comes from `commands.cooldown` not from BucketType

Comment: Are you sure it comes from this? Do you have other commands or something that deals with a cooldown?

Comment: Do you have a command called `commands`? Or a subcommand?

Comment: Yes and that was that. Thanks for helping me have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the same issue as I did, this is because you have a command named "commands"/"command". You will need to remove/rename it.